# Extract from values from different columns based on a list of indices to form a long-format dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` and a list `mylist`:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    location    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
M01 1   A   H   H   A   A   B
M02 2   A   H   A   A   A   B
M03 3   A   B   A   A   A   B
M04 4   H   B   H   A   A   B
M05 5   H   B   H   A   A   B
M06 6   A   B   H   A   A   H
M07 7   A   B   H   B   A   H
M08 8   A   B   H   A   A   H
M09 9   A   B   H   A   A   H
M10 10  B   B   H   A   A   H
M11 11  A   B   H   A   A   H
M12 12  A   B   H   A   A   H
M13 13  A   B   H   A   A   H
M14 14  B   B   B   A   A   H
M15 15  B   B   B   A   A   A", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

mylist = list(C1 = c(3,   5,   9,   10,  13), C2 = c(2) , 
C3 = c(1,   3,   13 ), C4 =c(6,   7 ), C6 = c(5,   14 ))
```

I would like to extract out values of columns `names(df)[-(1:2)]` based on indices in a list `mylist` and with the first two columns `names(df)[1:2]` together to form a long format data frame as:

```
ID   location   value   colname
M03 3   A   C1
M05 5   H   C1
M09 9   A   C1
M10 10  B   C1
M13 13  A   C1
M02 2   H   C2
M01 1   H   C3
M03 3   A   C3
M13 13  H   C3
M06 6   A   C4
M07 7   B   C4
M05 5   B   C6
M14 14  H   C6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the first two columns in the expected output by `unlist`ing the 'mylist', use that as row index to extract the rows from the first row columns of 'df', the 'value' column is created by extracting the elements of corresponding columns of 'df' with the 'mylist' elements as index in `Map` and `unlist` the `list` output, and the final 'colname' is the replicate of the `names` of 'mylist' by the `lengths` of the `list`.

```
r1 <- transform(df[unlist(mylist), 1:2],value = unlist(Map(`[`, df[names(mylist)], mylist)), 
       colname = rep(names(mylist), lengths(mylist)))
row.names(r1) <- NULL
r1
#   ID location value colname
#1  M03        3     A      C1
#2  M05        5     H      C1
#3  M09        9     A      C1
#4  M10       10     B      C1
#5  M13       13     A      C1
#6  M02        2     H      C2
#7  M01        1     H      C3
#8  M03        3     A      C3
#9  M13       13     H      C3
#10 M06        6     A      C4
#11 M07        7     B      C4
#12 M05        5     B      C6
#13 M14       14     H      C6
```